# button background turns black after click

Tags: java, swing, background, jbutton

I set my JButton with this properties:
 - borderPainted to false
 - contentAreaFilled to false
 - border to null
 - opaque to false

and after click on the button, the background turns black or fades to black color,
but why,.. any suggestions!? (thx)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the background shouldn't be painted, because a big background is behind the button (so opaque to false).. but when I click the button, the background of the button turns black

Comment: *"any suggestions!?"*  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Ask a **specific** question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a transparent button you need only to [`setContentAreaFilled(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled%28boolean%29), **do not call `setOpaque`**, see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled%28boolean%29) (Just note that the last line in the javadoc suggests that varies by Look and Feel,.):

> Sets the contentAreaFilled property. If true the button will paint the content area. **If you wish to have a transparent button, such as an icon only button, for example, then you should set this to false.** *Do not call setOpaque(false).* The default value for the the contentAreaFilled property is true.
>
> This function may cause the component's opaque property to change.
>
> *The exact behavior of calling this function varies on a component-by-component and L&F-by-L&F basis.*

If you "just want" text (and no border) you can call `setBorder(null)`.

---

### Example:

*...with no border and no background (and no "pressed" background). Tested on default look and feel for unity/ubuntu e.g `MetalLookAndFeel`.*

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Button") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // Printout to verify that the button was actually pressed
            // since no visual output is shown... :)
            System.out.println("Clicked");
        }
    });
    
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setBorder(null);
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(button);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```